# Is there a method out of the box for a dynamic two step approval process?

Tags: power-automate, o365-flow

Many of our organizational request forms are two step approval forms. A manager/supervisor and a director approve. The requestor sends the form to a manager who forwards it to the next approver. The requestor often has no knowledge of who that second level approver is. It is not feasible to keep a predefined approval list for this process and so we cannot define these approver chains beforehand.

Is there a way to create approvals where during the initial approval the approver can designate who the next approver is in the chain?

I have looked into custom responses, but they do not allow for additional information. Also the approval response only has a custom text for additional information and ideally we would like that to be a person picker.

Comment: Look into using an adaptive card.